# Is there a way to find out the date a user was disabled in Active Directory?

Tags: date, active-directory, user-accounts, last-modified, user-data

I'm currently working on Active Directory and I need to know when have certain accounts been disabled. There is the last_modified (a date) property but I'm not sure if enabling/disabling an account on AD triggers a change on last_modified. If yes, are there other properties that change it too when they are modified (which is probably the case...) ?

Is there a way to know for sure when an account has been disabled, either by checking a property or executing a cmd/powershell script ?

Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Kind of. But it won't be 100% reliable.

To disable an account, the `userAccountControl` attribute is updated.

Yes, updating `userAccountControl` will trigger an update to the `whenChanged` attribute (the "last modified" date).

There is also a computed attribute called `msDS-ReplAttributeMetaData` that will tell you when attributes were changed, as long as that feature is enabled on your domain. With the help from [this article](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/adpowershell/2009/11/01/accessing-replication-metadata-using-adpowershell/), I put some code together to pull out the last time the `userAccountControl` attribute was changed (set `$username` to the name of the account you want to look at):

```bsh
$username = "whatever"
$metaData = "<root>" + (Get-ADUser $username -Properties "msDS-ReplAttributeMetaData")."msDS-ReplAttributeMetaData".Replace([char]0," ") + "</root>"
$xmlmetaData = [XML]$metaData
$userAccountControlModified = ($xmlmetaData.root.DS_REPL_ATTR_META_DATA |
                               Where {$_.pszAttributeName -eq "userAccountControl" } |
                               Sort -Property ftimeLastOriginatingChange -Descending |
                               Select -First 1).ftimeLastOriginatingChange
```

However, as the [documentation for `userAccountControl`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/305144/how-to-use-useraccountcontrol-to-manipulate-user-account-properties) shows, that attribute is a bit flag that turns on and off several options for the account, not just enabled/disabled.

So while you can get the date the last time `userAccountControl` was updated, you cannot guarantee that's the time the account was disabled. It's possible that any other of those options were set after it was disabled.