# Can I pull a report of which Active Directory users were disabled manually vs which users had their account expire?

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap-query

Some of our users are set up with an expiration date. If all goes accordingly, when that date comes, their account expires and that kicks off a process in which a .txt file with some of their attributes is created and saved in a specified location. This is the happy path.

On occasion, we have to disable a user manually before the expiration date arrives. When we disable them manually, the process is not initiated and no .txt file is created/saved.

My problem right now is that I have a fair number of disabled users that I have to go back and audit. I'm going to have to manually create the .txt files for any users that did not expire automatically, if that makes sense. I'm wondering if there's a way to report on this in AD so that I can tell which users were disabled manually.

I feel like this could be possible with LDAP queries, but I'm not sure. I'm relatively new to using AD and I'm not familiar enough with attributes to know if the method of disabling is logged.

As an example, I had a user today that I had to disable manually. However, the accountExpires attribute is still set to 12/1/2021. I think I may be able to use the whenChanged attribute to do this. If whenChanged doesn't match the timestamp for accountExpires, then that would be a clue they were disabled manually. However I'll have to test this and see if automatic expiration affects whenChanged

Edit: simplified, my questions are:

- Is there an attribute that shows when an account was disabled/expired? (not just when an expiration was scheduled, but when the account was actually turned off)
- Is there an attribute that indicates how an account was disabled/expired? (meaning, did someone right-click on the user and choose 'Disable Account' or did the expiration date pass?)

Comment: "Is there an attribute that shows when an account was disabled/expired?" No; that would be in the audit data. "Is there an attribute that indicates how an account was disabled/expired?" Similar answer to first question. If an admin disabled the account, that would be in the audit data. If the "disabled" flag is not set and the date and time is past the expiration date, then that's why the user can't log on.

Comment: Thank you @Bill_Stewart - this is helpful. I found a related question that has some good information too.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58937386/is-there-a-way-to-find-out-the-date-a-user-was-disabled-in-active-directory

I'm going to try and figure out a way to pull a report that's close enough for my purposes by using the userAccountControl attribute. I'll try and post an answer here soon.

Comment: @rodstewart user AccountControls shows only Account is disabled or enabled.  For enabled it is Normal.

Comment: The `userAccountControl` attribute is a _bitmap_ value, which means it is an integer where each bit in the integer represents a boolean value. For example, if the `ADS_UF_ACCOUNTDISABLE` bit (bit 2) is a 1, then the account is disabled; if the bit is not set (0), the account is enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you create any user in AD (group) default set the user never expire. You can pull the users  that has set the expiration date manually.

AccountExpires value is always a FileTime value of 132789024000000000 UNLESS you modify a user to expire at which point. The AccountExpires value changes to 0 for never expire.

**PowerShell command for disabled user with their expiry date.**

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity TestGroup | get-aduser -Properties * | where {$_.Enabled -eq $false} | Select-Object -Property UserPrincipalName,AccountExpirationDate,AccountExpires | Export-CSV 'C:\test.csv'
```

[image]

In the above screenshot Ipsita and Kartik has set manually to expire so that their value is 132789024000000000 and where Ansuman has set for never expire user, so its value is 0.

**So here is your final PowerShell command for the user is set to expire manually.**

```
Get-ADGroupMember -Identity TestGroup | get-aduser -Properties * | where {$_.Enabled -eq $false -and $_.AccountExpirationDate -ne $null} | Select-Object -Property UserPrincipalName,AccountExpirationDate,AccountExpires | Export-CSV 'C:\test.csv'
```

[image]

whenChanged and Expiration date both are different attribute . whenChanged only display the timestamp of the changed properties of an object in an AD Whether that may be expiration date or anyother attribute of that particular object

Comment: Thanks - this will catch some of our cases, but not all. I should have been more specific in my question. Say that I set the user expiration date for 10/31/2021, but then I go and manually expire the user on 9/30/2021. Even when the user is disabled, the Account tab still shows "Account expires End of: 10/31/2021" and these are the users that I am concerned about.

Comment: Can you add more details? i can check it again.

Comment: As an example, I had a user today that I had to disable manually. However, the accountExpires attribute is still set to 12/1/2021. I think I may be able to use the whenChanged attribute to do this. If whenChanged doesn't match the timestamp for accountExpires, then that would be a clue they were disabled manually. However I'll have to test this and see if automatic expiration affects whenChanged.

Comment: @rodstewart for your above comment it is correct working for me . I changed the expiry date getting the updated expire date . Please execute with above PowerShell which i have gave.

Comment: @rodstewart for your second comment and updated question . You are confusing with whenChanged and Expiration date both are different attribute . whenChanged only display the timestamp of the changed properties of an object in an AD .Whether that may be expiration date or anyother attribute of  that particular object.

Comment: I know that whenChanged and accountExpires are different attributes. What I need is an attribute that shows when an account was disabled. I haven't been able to find one yet but maybe I'm not looking in the right place.

Comment: AD does not store the date and time of when an account was disabled in an attribute. That information would be in the audit log.

Comment: Yes agree on @Bill_Stewart.

Comment: Look at the security logs and filter / search for event ID # 4725 (it's event 629 in Windows Server 2003 ). This will tell you when the user ID was disabled. It will also tell you who did it. Reference : https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/lync/en-US/5bba3db5-825c-406b-9da7-bdceeddcff09/how-to-know-when-was-an-account-disabled?forum=winserverDS